# Auto Sort Date Column

Tags: excel

I worksheet containing following data (sheet name _ BDAY)
A Column : Date   B Column Name   C Column Year

All the data in column is assorted manner

[image]

I want this to be sorted out in another sheet name (Current Bday) 
the sorting should be as per the Month & date wise. The Current Bday sheet shold be auto sort as I enter new row in BDAY sheet. I have got around 950 rows in Bday sheet & much more to enter.

Answer (score 0):

user3705748.

I hope it helps.

First of all, I would add an additional column to your first sheet (_BDAY), so that it looks like this:

**DATE (Column A)** | **MONTH (Column B)** | **NAME (Column C)** | **AGE (Column D)**

In column B, you will use the formula =MONTH(), making a reference to column A (date). This way you will get the month for each date. The new layout should look like this:

[image]

Second step: add a pivot table. Select range "A:D" in sheet _BDAY, and insert the pivot table in sheet Current Bday.

[image]

Third. Add row fields like this:

[image]

Your pivot table will look like this:

[image]

Now, let's change the look of the pivot (step four). Right click on the pivot and click on Pivot Table Options...

[image]

Go to Display and click on checkbox "Classic pivot table...."

[image]

Remove subtotals per month, date and name:

[image]

This is how your final pivot should look like:

[image]

As you enter new items in sheet _BDAY, just refresh the pivot in order to drag them into the pivot (right click on the pivot):

[image]

Go to any position in the month column inside the pivot and sort as you prefer. It also works with other fields (date, name, age).

[image]

Please let me know if it was helpful.

Comment: Thank You ... But it is not sorting the date

Comment: Please upload a screenshot to check your results. It should work.

Comment: Thank a lot for your help. I did some changes and it's working. Thank you so much